# Check efficiently if ratios of two expressions is a number

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have a kind of dumb question I'm afraid.

Given two complicated expressions, is there a fast check to see whether one is a rational multiple of the other. I mean given expressions `expr1, expr2` something like `NumberQ[expr1/expr2]`. However `NumberQ[Simplify[expr1/expr2]]` does exactly what I need but might take forever! Is there a faster way?

By the way I have no idea how to tag this question...

Comment: If `Simplify` is too slow I think you need to do it approximately like `Rationalize[expr1/expr2, 10^(-tol)] === Rationalize[expr1/expr2, 10^(-2*tol)]` with e.g. `tol = 100`

Comment: Could you add a "typical" example of `expr1` and `expr2`?

Comment: Both expressions are polynomials with a lot of terms adding up in n variables with integer coefficients here. They are found themselves from certain types of graphs which I input. Sometimes two completely different graphs yield proportional polynomials although you can only see it after a lot of algebraic simplifications

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach is to evaluate the polynomials with random integers assigned to the variables.  This is likely to be very fast.

For test purposes, let us define 3 polynomials in 7 variables

```
expr1a = (-2 + a[1]) (-5 + a[2]) (5 + a[3]) (4 + a[4]) (1 + a[5]) a[6] (-4 + a[7]);
expr1b = Expand[13/7 expr1a];
expr2 = expr1b + 1;
```

Define functions

```
randominstance[x_] := Block[{a},
  Do[a[i] = RandomInteger[{-1000, 1000}], {i, 7}];
  x]
ratiocheck[x1_, x2_] := SameQ[randominstance[x1/x2], randominstance[x1/x2]]
```

Test that the functions give the expected results on our test polynomials

```
ratiocheck[expr1a, expr1b]
(* True *)

ratiocheck[expr1a, expr2]
(* False *)
```

There is a risk of concluding that two polynomials have a constant ratio, when in fact they do not, but you can do multiple checks.

Comment: Thanks this works beautifully... I guess a triple check is quite safe...